# Laravel Eloquent Relationship: Do we use relationship count or collection count if we already eager loaded the relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two major questions, both related to eloquent's eager loading.

## First question:

Since we already eager loaded the relationship, we have the loaded objects right there. For example,
 `Tag::with('posts');`
will eager load all the posts for the tags. Then if I want to count the number of posts for the first tag, would it be better to use `Tag::first()->posts()->count()` or `Tag::first()->posts->count()`?

I know normally the answer would be the first one, because we dont want to load all the collections and instead we want to just do it using one query. However, in this case I assume we already loaded the collections, so it's like we already paid the cost, and therefore I feel like the second one would be better in this case?

Side Note:
I understand we can use `withCount('posts')` in this case, but my point here is to understand when to use relationship count vs collection count.

## Second question:

I am also wondering if we already used `Tag::with('posts')`, then if I want to count the posts for the first tag, would it be faster using `Tag::first()->posts()->count / Tag::first( )->posts->count` or using `Tag::withCount('posts')->with('posts')`
My logistics behind this is that `withCount()` is fast if we only need the count, but what if we already loaded the relationship and at the same time also want to get the count?

Answer (score 0):

Counting is costly depending on how large your database is. One common approach is to use caching. With large databases, faster almost always means using cache, but caching will not be 100% accurate since cache should be updated at set times.

And, if you are going to run count on a large collection, you are bound to face memory issues.

For the first one, you could learn a lot using a debugger to analyse what's happening using each method. Do also take note of laravel's `loadCount()` method.